# Topological property of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> > $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (when $D \subseteq R$) is continuous function if and only if for all open set $G$, $f^{-1}(G)$ is also open set on $D$.

I want to prove the $\Rightarrow$ of this theorem. The following is the proof in my textbook.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $D$ and $G$ be an open set, $H:=f^{-1}(G)$. If $H\cap D = \phi$, it is done. If $H\cap D \not = \phi$, let $a \in H \cap D$, and $b:=f(a)$, then $b\in G$. Since $G$ is open set, there exists an open ball $B_\epsilon(b) \subseteq G$ radius of which is $\epsilon>0$. By the assumption $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta : \forall x \in B_\delta (a) \cap D \rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| <\epsilon$. **This means that $B_\delta (a) \subseteq f^{-1}(G)$**, so that $f^{-1}(G)$ is open set.

I don't understand the bold part of the proof that it derive $B_\delta (a) \subseteq f^{-1}(G)$.

I haven't studied metric space and general topology, so explain me more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence $\exists \delta : \forall x \in B_\delta (a) \cap D \rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| <\epsilon$ says that for any $x \in B_\delta(a)\cap D$, $f(x)$ is an element of $B_\epsilon(b)$. But $B_\epsilon(b)$ was chosen to be *inside* $G$, so we have $f(x) \in G$. That is exactly the same as saying that $x \in f^{-1}(G)$.

So any $x$ that is inside $B_\delta(a)\cap D$ is also inside $f^{-1}(G)$, and therefore  $B_\delta(a)\cap D \subseteq f^{-1}(G)$. The set $B_\delta(a)\cap D$ might not be open in $R$, but it is an open $\delta$-ball in $D$, surrounding our arbitrary $a$, contained in $f^{-1}(G)$, and therefore we're done.

Comment: In the question the expression $x\in B_{\delta}(a)\cap D$ is practicized. That is an indication that $x\in B_{\delta}(a)\cap D^c$ is not necessarily empty. In that case there are elements in $B_{\delta}(a)$ that do not belong to $f^{-1}(G)$.

Comment: @drhab We are asked to show that $f^{-1}(G)$ is open _in_ $D$. That means that we can consider $D$ as the entire space, and therefore we are done. I will edit, though.

Comment: Yes. In fact the use of expression $B_{\delta}(a)\cap D$ in the textbook is the disturbing thing, and asks for care. Just $B_{\delta}(a)$ with eventually some explanation would have been better there.

Answer (score 1):

I would plead for: "This means that $B_{\delta}(a)\cap D\subseteq f^{-1}(G)$"

Though, if $B_{\delta}(a)$ is immediately defined as subset of $D$ in metric space $D$ then you can also do it with $B_{\delta}(a)$ itself.

If $x\in B_{\delta}(a)\cap D$ then we have $f(x)\in B_{\epsilon}(b)\subseteq G$, right?

Well, the statements $f(x)\in G$ and $x\in f^{-1}(G)$ are equivalent. So we have:

$$x\in B_{\delta}(a)\cap D\implies x\in f^{-1}(G)$$

This comes to the same as: $$B_{\delta}(a)\cap D\subseteq f^{-1}(G)$$

Comment: Then in the question's proof, is there no verification that $f^{-1}(G)$ is open set in $D$? I learned that $A$ is open on D if and only if there exists open set $G$ in $R$ that $A =G \cap D$, but this proof doesn't mention it.

Comment: It is proved in the textbook that for some arbitrary $a\in D$ function $f$ is continuous at $a$. Then it is continuous at any element of $D$ and this fact is equivalent with: $f$ is continuous. What you learned is okay and in fact we can write $f^{-1}(G)=U\cap D$ where $U$ is the union of the open balls $B_{\delta}(a)$ that satisfy $B_{\delta}(a)\cap D\subseteq f^{-1}(G)$ for $a\in D$. This union is open itself.